# Gender details for Google ads

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm obviously missing something really obvious.  If I use the standard report I can analyse the data by gender very easily.  If I download the data via the API I can't find a gender field at all.  I have a LOT of tables, but no field named gender (or anything close) or a field that contains gender details.

What am I missing in my understanding?

Comment: I have no experience with this specific api, but have you researched on a [page like this yet](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/gender_view)?

Comment: Thanks bit, but the correct link is https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/gender_view and if the information is there, I can't understand it :(

Comment: Don't worry! Google's API(s) are mostly confusing at first (and all of the times I tried adopting their APIs). I'll try to dig in the documentation with you.

Comment: [Might help in the future once you find that gender column/row](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/data/codes-formats?hl=en)

Comment: [Similar question that has already been answered](https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/4qvLzLOdFdw)